# How to use SSRS report in mvc razor using MvcReportViewer 0.4.0 package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, reporting-services, nuget-package

How can i use the ssrs report within MVC razor application. I have downloaded MvcReportViewer 0.4.0 package from NuGet package source. what i need to do further and how i can use this package in cshtml?

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend going to this page, "https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer". It have all the information you need to use the package.